# tox skipped because could not find python interpreter

Tags: python, tox

I am having a problem using *tox*. I have to say first that I am not an expert on  virtual environments, and I prefer to use *conda* environments, I find them much more easy to use and understand.

So as the background of my system I have a Ubuntu 18 system, where Python is 3.6.9. I also have a *conda* environment where Python is 3.9.16, and an *Anaconda* base environment with Python 3.8.3

Anyway I want to use tox for testing with this `tox.ini` file

```
[tox]
envlist=py37
skipsdist = True

[testenv]
deps=pytest
commands= pytest
```

After installing *tox* (and I installed it in both inside the conda environment and outside), when I ran `tox` I got:

```
py37: skipped because could not find python interpreter with spec(s): py37
```

I get it, *pytest 3.7* is not installed.
But I thought that is what virtual environments do... what is the point of me using *tox* if I have to install manually the version ?
And if I want to test it with multiple versions, do I have to install manually every version?

And what is more important, how can I install several versions?

With *conda* I have one version per environment.
How can I use *tox* efficiently here?

Comment: Note that this message may be misleading because it also shows up for problems otherwise related to building your package. For example, I saw this because of a syntax error in my setup.cfg. The crucial thing for me was to study the stack traces and error messages in the output above; for me they showed up as indented blocks of red print.

Answer (score 3):

[*tox*](https://pypi.org/project/tox/) requires Python interpreters to already be installed beforehand. How the Python interpreters get installed is not *tox*'s concern.

Some ideas to install multiple additional Python interpreters:

- [*deadsnakes*](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) which is specific to Ubuntu
- [*pyenv*](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)
- there are ways to let *tox* use Python interpreters installed by *conda*, [here maybe some actionable suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tox%20conda)

Answer (score 1):

It's not the version pytest which is wrong, `py37` refers to Python version 3.7, so it didn't find the interpreter associated with it.

You can install it in Ubuntu 18.04 by:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.7
```

To use effectively *tox* you need to learn how to configure properly the `tox.ini` file and how the *tox* environments works. To start any `py3X` will execute the commands (usually `pytest`) in your main environment, usually defined as `testenv` with the version 3.X of Python.

Other tip is to use the flag `-p` for parallel execution of different environments, e.g. `tox -p -e py37,py39` which will execute `testenv` in `python3.7` and `python3.9` simultaneously.

Comment: So I have to install manually every python interpreter I need? (tox does not do that for me?)

Comment: Yes, tox does not install pythons. You can use [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to install several versions, manage them (e.g. upgrade when new minor is released), and remove outdated/unused. It can also serve as venv provider, though it's not very convenient IMO. `pyenv` will download, build and install requested python without root. You can enable several versions with `pyenv local`.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Thanks!. Does that mean tox requires pyenv? I don't see the point of using tox then if that is the case

Comment: tox does not require pyenv. tox requires Python interpreters to already be installed beforehand. How the Python interpreters get installed is not tox's concern.